# Flutter - json filter listview

Tags: flutter, dart

im new to flutter, I have a local json file as shown below, managed to show it in my UI, and showed the filter/search bar as well but now im trying to make the filter listview function. I tried few things but it did not work out. How do I compare the user input to the data in my JSON file ? I was wondering how to make the search function works for "name"?

```
{
    "name": "Telekinesis",
    "description": "Rubick uses his telekinetic powers to lift the enemy into the air briefly and then hurls them back at the ground.",
    "logo_url": "http://static.wikia.nocookie.net/dota2_gamepedia/images/0/0e/Telekinesis_icon.png"
  },
```

---

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Header'),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  TextEditingController controller = new TextEditingController();

  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Center(child: Text(widget.title)),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: "Search Title",
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide:
                            BorderSide(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor))),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: FutureBuilder(
                future: DefaultAssetBundle.of(context)
                    .loadString('components/abilities-list.json'),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  var myData = jsonDecode(snapshot.data.toString());
                  return ListView.builder(
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                      return ListTile(
                          leading: CircleAvatar(
                              backgroundImage:
                                  NetworkImage(myData[index]['logo_url'])),
                          title: Text('Name: ' + myData[index]['name']),
                          subtitle: Text(
                            'Description: ' + myData[index]['description'],
                          ));
                    },
                    itemCount: myData == null ? 0 : myData.length,
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

com/users/14288499/muhammad-medani
make a Data class of like

```
class JSONData {
  String name;
  String description;
  String logoUrl;

  JSONData({this.name, this.description, this.logoUrl});

  JSONData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    name = json['name'];
    description = json['description'];
    logoUrl = json['logo_url'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['description'] = this.description;
    data['logo_url'] = this.logoUrl;
    return data;
  }
}
```

when you will get the data from the future builder then pass this snapshot.data to the fromJson method so you will get the objects of it and then you can search as well.
make a `List<JSONData> data= [];` like this and then you can access it in listview builder and search as well like this

```
data.forEach((userDetail) {
      if (data.name.contains(text) || data.name.contains(text))
        _searchResult.add(userDetail);
    });
```